# How Can I fillup bootstrap grid using foreach?

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach, twitter-bootstrap-2, col

As I am trying to make bootstrap grid structure using `foreach` two column and inside it's one row and two rows structure. Attached a screen shot for better to better view.

Note: Not issue with CSS but first three items are goes in grid as picture.

Counter is not taking `col-md-4` and not sure where to use Counter increment `counter++`? What if I want to show first three items using `foreach`?

Any other way to workaround on this layout? Tried so far as below

```
  <?php $counter = 0;
            foreach($view->result as $result) {

      <div id="hot-post" class="row hot-post">      
            <?php if( $counter == 0 || $counter % 3 == 0 ) {    ?> 
            <div class="col-md-8 hot-post-left">
                <div class="post post-thumb">
                    // first element common body 

                </div>
            </div>

       <?php if( $counter == 1 || $counter == 2 ) { ?> 
          <div class="col-md-4 hot-post-right">
           <?php if( $counter == 1){ ?>
                <div class="post post-thumb">
                    // second element common body 
                 </div>

          </php if ( $counter == 2){
                <div class="post post-thumb">
                    // third element common body 
                 </div>
          </div>
         <?php counter++; } } ?>
       </div> //closing row 
      <?php } ?>  //closing foreach
```

[image]

Comment: You may want to look at this to make your code easier to read when mixing PHP and HTML like you're doing here: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of syntax errors in your code, such as:

- Opening and closing braces are not in sync i.e. `foreach` loop and `if` block(s) are not closed properly
- `counter++;` should be `$counter++;`

Plus, there are few logical errors as well. Change your code in the following way,

```
<?php 
    $counter = 0;
    foreach($view->result as $result) { 
    ?>
        <div id="hot-post" class="row hot-post">      
        <?php if( $counter == 0 || $counter % 3 == 0 ) { ?> 
            <div class="col-md-8 hot-post-left">
                <div class="post post-thumb">
                    // first element common body 
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if( $counter != 0 && $counter % 3 != 0 ) { ?> 
            <div class="col-md-4 hot-post-right">
            <?php if( $counter % 3 == 1){ ?>
                <div class="post post-thumb">
                    // second element common body 
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php if ( $counter % 3 == 2){ ?>
                <div class="post post-thumb">
                    // third element common body 
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    <?php
        }
        ++$counter;
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Great! that works. due to copy-paste forgot to add Opening and closing braces but the main issue is `counter++` and if condition

Comment: @Nisarg, Glad I could help! :-) I don't think the *suggested edit* is necessary, given the current problem at hand.